# 3D scatter plot from a txt file

Tags: plotting, import, text

I have a txt file with space-delimited x, y, z coordinates of several points. The points are organized into groups of unequal size; the groups are delimited by skipping a line, like this:

```
2.3 3.4 5.5
2.4 3.3 5.6
2.5 3.5 5.6

1.2 4.3 3.3
0.7 4.0 3.5

-1.2 1.3 -0.7
-1.1 1.7 -0.5
```

I can't find a way to have *Mathematica* just import these then plot the points! I've tried searching a little bit but didn't find a similar question.

When plotting, it's not important to distinguish from which group each point came from. For example, I don't need different colours for each group or anything like that.

Answer (score 8):

I would use:

```
dat = ReadList["file.txt", Number, RecordLists -> True];

ListPointPlot3D[dat, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`"file.txt"` is of course the name (and if necessary the path) of your data file.

Thanks to the default option [`NullRecords -> False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NullRecords.html) any extra lines are omitted from `dat`.

Answer (score 3):

```
dat = Import["F:/data.txt", "Table"] /. {} -> Sequence[];
ListPointPlot3D[dat]
```

Comment: Even better is the option of import `"IgnoreEmptyLines"->True`

Comment: @Ajasja with that option this is a good method for data types that `ReadList` does not easily recognize.  For regular numeric data it's bound to be slower than `ReadList` however.