# Importing a matrix from a text file

Tags: matrix, import

I have a $4 \times N$ matrix in a .txt file of the form:

> -17.071    137.567 16.554  0.65
>
> -16.873    136.138 16.934  0.7
>
> -15.397    135.738 16.894  0.7
>
> -14.7  135.982 15.9    0.6
>
> ... ($N-4$ additional row entries)

Where the numeric values in each row are separated by a space. How would I read this matrix in, and parse it in the following manner:

```
{ 
  {-17.071, 137.567, 16.554, 0.65},
  {-16.873, 136.138, 16.934, 0.7},
  {-15.397, 135.738, 16.894, 0.7},
  {-14.7, 135.982, 15.9, 0.6},
  ...
}
```

Evaluating

```
Import[PATH\\MATRIX.txt]]
```

Only returns the printed contents of the file.

Comment: Please upload the file somewhere so that we can help you better.

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20361/61)?

Comment: i have a same question my file path is D:\ and my file name is f.txt
so how can i import in mathematica?

Comment: @HafizFahad did you see the accepted answer here? If `Import[ filename , "Table" ]` doesn't work I'd guess your file is structured differently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect that

```
data = Import[PATH\\MATRIX.txt, "Table"]
```

could work for you, however, I'm not sure without a copy of your file. If you post that I will try to update this answer.

Comment: Works!  ReadList[PATH\\MATRIX.txt, {Number, Number, Number, Number}] also worked.

Comment: You need a double quota for PATH\\MATRIX.txt